# ShouldJS `should.equal` throws JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I've run into an issue where running `mocha` tests a simple check of `should.equal(reactComponent, undefined)` fail with `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`.

Answer (score 0):

I've traced the issue into `should-format.js` file inside `should-format` node module version `3.0.3`.
It seems that the fact the `actual` parameter was a React component cause the failure when trying to format the error message.

A simple workaround is to rewrite the assert this way: `(reactComponent === undefined).should.be.true();`